# Cannot get a google site verified despite a valid Analytics Tracking ID

Tags: google-analytics, google-sites

I have created a web site on the Google platform: 
https://sites.google.com/site/golfshotpilot/
Furthermore I have made all administrational steps to get the site's analytics. In this context I got a Tracking ID. The tracking works. I get the reports and statistics. (Evidences below).
However when I use the Google Webmaster Tool, the system will not verify my account for my own website. I have tried the verification based on the uploaded HTML file. It did not work. Then I tried to apply the authentication via my Tracking ID of the Analytics Tool. This did not work either. The error message is: The Google Analytics tracking code on your site looks malformed. 
How can this be when the tracking id is obviously OK?

Any ideas for help?

Error screen:
[image: Webmaster page with error]

Definition about the Analytics in the site management settings:
[image]

Evidence that the code is existing in the web sites source data:
[image: Evidence of code existence]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about Google analytics setup and is not programing related may be better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I was not aware of this platform. I have placed my question there now.

Comment: @PeterMattheisen What's the new URL? Too bad StackOverflow admins can't move the question, rather than "complain and close" which isn't very helpful.